# How to use variable package selector in go

Tags: go

I'm following the Go tour, and still trying to learn the basics of the language. For the imported package `time`, is there a way to access its exports with a variable? E.g. `time[day]` instead of `time.Saturday`

Here's a more complete example

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    day := "Thursday"
    fmt.Printf("When's %v?", day)
    today := time.Now().Weekday()
    switch time[day] { // This is how I would do it in javascript
    case today + 0:
        fmt.Println("Today.")
    default:
        fmt.Println("Too far away.")
    }
}
```

Also, what is the correct terminology for what I want to do? I'm having very little luck using Google

Comment: negative votes without an explanation are so useless

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way to reference exported variables from a package, which are stored on the stack, without explicitly referencing them using a data structure that you define that's built at runtime.

For example, you could do:

```
var days = map[string]time.Weekday{
  "Monday":    time.Monday,
  "Tuesday":   time.Tuesday,
  "Wednesday": time.Wednesday,
  "Thursday":  time.Thursday,
  "Friday":    time.Friday,
  "Saturday":  time.Saturday,
  "Sunday":    time.Sunday,
}
fmt.Println(days["Thursday"])
```

See http://play.golang.org/p/6EYqcklf8X